# Removing float from horizontal list menu while retaining dropdown

Tags: css

I have a horizontal navigation menu that breaks upon browser window resize as illustrated here:
https://jsfiddle.net/7oLjwh90/2/

Now the culprit here is:

```
#adminNav ul li { float: left;
```

But as soon as i remove float and do display: inline-block for example the dropdown stop working. It becomes a pure mess.

Tried setting display to inline-block and also recreated a new simple horizontal menu and that behaves as expected but cant get this dropdown to work without float.

https://jsfiddle.net/7oLjwh90/2/

Same menu as on https://jsfiddle.net/7oLjwh90/2/ but it doesnt break upon browser window resize. The list items should not stack on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you wish to achieve. If removing the float property is your problem, you can try using flexbox(here is some good information on the matter -https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). If this doesn't work for you, specify your question further. Hope this is useful.

Comment: Flexbox did the trick :) Well using float makes the list items break when the user resizes the browser window. So i was trying to make a menu without float but that breaks my dropdown menu for some reason. But Flexbox was a much better solution and dont have the pitfalls of floating. Thanks man!

Comment: Glad it helped!